# NumberFormat with 0 decimals, but thousands separator " ' "

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have whole numbers like: `14'119'838` - it also can just be 0. If I try this:

```
Range("C3:H14").NumberFormat = "0"
```

The Apostrophe-thousand-separator disappears. If I set the NumberFormat to "General", there is no thousands separator.... How can I have 0 decimal places, but with the beautiful thousands separator?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your Number Fromat to this:

```
Range("C3:H14").NumberFormat = "#'###'##0"
```

if you use this `Range("C3:H14").NumberFormat = "#,##0"` Formula you will get the English Number format.
Since you ask for the " ' " Seperartor you will need the **"#'###'##0"** Number Format to get the Swiss Number Format.

---

Code for changing the NumberFormat by the length of the Number

```
For Each Rng In Range("a1:B5")

 Select Case Len(Rng.Value) 'hier Spalte A
    Case Is < 4: Rng.NumberFormat = "##0"

    Case 4 To 6: Rng.NumberFormat = "#'##0"

    Case 7 To 11: Rng.NumberFormat = "#'###'##0"

    End Select
    Next
```

Comment: This results in 2 Problems: 1. a few cells are 0, so after changing the format this will be " '0 ". 2. Problem is that this ignores the second or Million separator. e.g. 1234'567 is not so pretty

Comment: @dv3 then change it to "#'###'##0"

Comment: @Moosli results in '343'424 for 343424. I think what dv3 wants is to get rid of the excess " ' " at the begining of a number. I think it might be done with `select case` but for that you need to run every cell in a range and it decreases perfomance for sure.

Comment: @AntiDrondert You got the problem exactly right - can you give my a code snipped? Performance is secondary, as the sheet is quite small

Answer (score 3):

Change your `NumberFormat` from `"0"` to:

```
Range("C3:H14").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Comment: That will give him the Englisch Number Format. But he aksed for the Swiss Number Format.

Comment: @Moosli sorry, where in his post it is mentioned ? I can't find any reference to the word swedish

Comment: first Switzerland <> Sweden... he didn't ask directly for it, but he gave en example how the Numbers should look. and in the Titel he ask for the thoussands separator with single quotation marks not with a 
comma

Comment: Same as the comment in the other answer - I want to avoid the thousand separator if the number is 0. Also I need a "millionth" separator, if the number is large enough

Comment: @dv3 you can try this solution. Excel should cange the Format by himself and you will have the right number format.

Comment: @Moosli see AntiDrondert's comment in the other answer

Answer (score 2):

Welp, sorry I'm late, here is another solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub again()
    Dim rng As Range
    set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:H14")
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "'"
    rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End Sub
```

If you have other number formats you do not want to separate with " ' " it won't do, since it replaces default Excel separator with " ' "